# what's the legal basis for Turbosquid claiming to be exclusive channel for Ford 3D model distribution?

Tags: copyright

Here's the link to the [Turbosquid Ford Agreement](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-modeling/general-info/terms-agreements/ford-artist-agreement/). Here's the [TLDR version](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-modeling/general-info/general-information-faqs/ford-artist-faq/)

Basically, the agreement claims that Turbosquid is the only place to sell Ford 3D models legally. (and that it is agreed with Ford)

Yet, there's a whole [cgtrader.com](https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/ford) section for Ford 3D models.

What's the basis for Turbosquid's claims? Can Ford use its copyright/trademark against distributing 3D models?

Answer (score 1):

This is unlikely to be a copyright issue as much as a Trademark issue.  It would appear that TurboSquid have an arrangement whereby people can make products which take 3d models which advantage of Ford branding.   Were you to create a model and use Ford Branding without the consent of Ford or there agent (Turbosquid=agent), you will most likely fall foul of trademark laws.

It would seem unlikely that, having acquired a trademarked item which was correctly licensed you could prevent the on-sale of the object through an unauthorized venue - however printing your own 3D models would be an act of creation, and would probably be a breach of trademark.   **Those 3d models for sale on cgtrader.com most would likely be found to not be legal should Ford pursue the sellers.**

As an aside, the Ford Artist Agreement at TurboSquid would not be binding on you unless you agreed to enter into it - however absent agreement from Ford or there agent you are not at liberty to use their trademark.

The only relevant information I could find from your links is in the Ford Artist FAQ which states "*TurboSquid is the only approved outlet for selling Ford related 3D Models. This means that Ford requires you to exclusively sell Ford related 3D models through TurboSquid, which has implemented their review process for buyers and sellers, whether you are a SquidGuild member or not."*